# One single client login session for all the feature file scenario tests in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My selenium java framework uses feature files and multiple scenario runs in parallel due but client doesnot allow multiple logins with same user credentials. How to utilise user session in scenarios instead of performing multiple login and logout and not to overwhelm client logins

login once, use the session in all the scenarios of feature file

Answer (score 0):

From the question it is not really clear how many users you have (1 in general? 1 per each feature?)

Typically when you log in to a website using a browser, the website's server will generate a session identifier (kinda token) and send it back to the browser as a cookie. This cookie is then stored by the browser and sent back with subsequent requests to the same website.

You can try to modify your LoginPage class to store a static session id, which should be retrieved from the cookies after the first login. You will need to synchronize the login method, to make sure that only one 'actual' login will happen.

After storing the session id, you can add it to the driver as a cookie, and the website should recognize your session as the 'logged-in' one (don't forget to refresh the page after adding a cookie).

So, the flow can be the following: 
Call the login method > Check if the session id is not null (sync check) > If it is null, do the actual login (it should be done from under check method, to force the other threads to wait for a while), retrieve and store the session id > after this the 'check session id' method should be unlocked for other threads, they should take non-null session id, set it to their driver, refresh the page and hopefully be logged in.

You can read about Selenium and cookies [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/cookies/).

It will add some minor delay (due to synchronization) to your tests, but I believe it should help you to handle the described problem.